# How could I prove that the equality $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$ in a semigroup with identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, semigroups

Let $S$ be a semigroup with a identity. How could I prove that the equality $a^na^m=a^{n+m}$ which holds for all $n,m \in \mathbb Z$. Note that $a \in S$ and $\mathbb Z$ denotes the set of all integers.

thanks for your help.

Comment: Unless either "semigroup" or "$Z$" means something unusual, I don't think these expressions are even defined in this generality.

Comment: I would guess the exercise is to prove it for $n,m \in \mathbb{N}$ where one includes $0$ in $\mathbb{N}$, given the semigroup is said to have an identity.

Comment: @coffeemath: The points you noted are right but I saw in some papers that $a^0b$ is used for $b$ for example.

Comment: I’m awfully sorry, but there is something so wrong with your grammar that I don’t know what you’re asking. Did you really mean to include both the word “that” and the word “which” in the second sentence?

Comment: @Lubin If you drop the word "which" it makes sense.

Comment: @coffeemath, yes, but if you instead drop the word “that”, it also makes somewhat different sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider 4 cases:

$m\ge 0, n\ge 0,$

$m\ge 0, n\le 0,$

$m\le 0, n\ge 0,$

$m\le 0, n\le 0.$

Have some difficulties?

Comment: Only the first of these cases works in some semigroups, for example in $\mathbb{N}$ under addition (but written in multiplicative notation).

Comment: @ coffeemath: Of course. But if OP writes "for all $n,m\in \math{Z}", I think he means that some of elements have inverses.

Comment: Boris: I agree, and more precisely it could be shown for "all $n,m,a$ for which the terms are all defined", meaning that *if* the chosen $a$ happens to be invertible in the semigroup, then the law stated holds for all $n,m \in \mathbb{Z}$, and otherwise one should restrict to exponents in $\mathbb{N}.$

Comment: @coffeemath: The question is worded vaguely, so I finished  the answer by the phrase "Have some difficulties?". I'm ready to write more details, if OP has a hardship.

Answer (score 0):

for the first case m≥0,n≥0, 
(a^n)(a^m)= aaa..a(m factor) * aaa...a (n factor)= aaa...a(m+n factor )= a^(m+n)

for the second and third use mathmatical induction and for the fourth use as what i use for the first but by -m and -n factor .